# c# and Android tcp communication on public ip

Tags: c#, android, tcp, server

I'm writing app on android, which would communicate with c# server via TCP protocol. My code works fine when I use wi-fi and now I want to change it that it would work even if android client would use mobile data
Server in c# (only recive and send data):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //setup
        Program prog = new Program();//to run non-static void from static context

        //main server 
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.x.xxx");
            // Initializes the Listener 
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 11000);
            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            //label com
            com:
            //accept connection
            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
            //recive data
            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            int k = s.Receive(b);

            char cc = ' ';
            string text = null;//wil produce recived text
            Console.Write("Recieved: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
                cc = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
                text += cc.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            //analyze text        
            string reply = prog.analyzeText(text);

            //send reply 
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();//is using to encode reply<string> to possible to send format 
            s.Send(asen.GetBytes(reply));//send
            s.Close();          

            /* clean up */
            goto com;
            s.Close();
            myList.Stop();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

and android client code:

```
private String connectSocket(String msg) {//send and receive data from server
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.x.xxx");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 11000);
        //define PrintWriter
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {              
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out.println(msg);
            String text = "";
            String finalText = "";
            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                finalText += text;
            }
            socket.close();
            return finalText;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong.\nTry again in few minutes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return "UnknownHostException";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "IOException";
    }
}
```

PS. sorry for my english, but I started learning it only 1 year ago

Answer (score 0):

There's no code changes needed.  You might need to set up your network correctly so there's no firewalls in the way around your test server (and that may include talking to your ISP, if they have a firewall preventing incoming connections).  But standard socket communication works over wifi or mobile.

Comment: oh, I see. I think my isp's firewalling me, couse when I disabled Windows Firewall and try 'telnet yourdomain.com 11000' it doesn't connect. Thanks for help

Comment: or it isn't. Now all firewalls are turned off, but connection still don't work.